# Relation between distance between vertices and an icosahedron.

Tags: geometry, symmetry, polyhedra

Prove/disprove the Lemma

$Lemma$ : There are 12 distinct vertices (Points) in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Given any vertex the minimum distance to another vertex is $1$ $unit$ and there are exactly 5 such neighboring vertices with the distance $1$ $unit$ from the given vertex. Any such 12 vertices form an Icosahedron.

Obviously it should be shown that any such 12 vertices form equilateral triangles of the Icosahedron. But I am unable to come up with any argument for the same.

All Help will be appreciated.